# 'init(systemName:)' is unavailable in macOS

Tags: swiftui

I would like to use SF Symbols in my macOS project. How to implement one?

```swift
Button(action: {}) {
  Image(systemName: "star") //Error: 'init(systemName:)' is unavailable in macOS            
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use San Francisco symbols on macOS SwiftUI development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078330/is-there-a-way-to-use-san-francisco-symbols-on-macos-swiftui-development)

Comment: I updated my question adding my solution to this issue. Perhaps you have comments.

Comment: Does it work with "star.fill" as in your example?

Comment: I added my answer

Comment: What about "guitar" from SF Symbols

Comment: <pre><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SMB1.png" width="100" height="100"></pre>

Comment: That's not what a guitar looks like

Comment: Oops, wrong url, https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kVOc.png

Comment: So maybe just post your answer under the question mentioned above, since this one is a duplicate.

Comment: I post my solution as an answer to this question or is it wrong?

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate and should be deleted, but your answer might help someone so maybe it is better to post it under the question which was asked first

Comment: I can delete this question and I marked it as duplicate  "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."

Comment: @LuLuGaGa I got it, `SF Symbols` app must be installed on macOS to show symbols

Answer (score 6):

It is nativly supporting from the **macOS 11** beta or later, then it works as usual, otherwise you have to export a template and import it to the assets catalog, then you can use it as a normal image. So:

```
if #available(OSX 11.0, *) {
    Image(systemName: "trash.fill")
} else {
    Image("trash.fill") // Imported as a supporting format like PDF (not SVG)
}
```

Another way is to use the symbol directly in the text:

```
Text("") // The symbol itself can not be shown on the markdown of the StackOverflow
```

[image: Demo]

<sub>Remember that you should embed the font in your application or the destination should have the SF Symbols App installed</sub>

Answer (score 3):

[Apple's Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/) state:

> You can use SF Symbols in apps running in iOS 13 and later, watchOS 6 and later, and tvOS 13 and later.

No Mac support at this time. ☹️

Comment: I updated my question adding my solution to this issue. Perhaps you have comments.

Comment: I suppose that works if you only have a few icons. Not sure if it would render on a machine that doesn't have SF Symbols installed, and no idea about the licensing ramifications.

Answer (score -1):

Before using this code you should install [SF Symbols app](https://developer.apple.com/design/downloads/SF-Symbols.dmg)

I make `Image` for macOS like below

[image]

that's how it looks on macOS

[image]

Comment: This will not work in computers that don't have the SF Symbols font installed.

Comment: Install SF Symbols for Mac from [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/downloads/SF-Symbols.dmg)

Comment: Sure, what about the users of your app though? Are you going to tell all of them to do that? Is that even going to pass app review at the App Store?

Comment: If you don't want to force users to install sf symbols app I can offer such a way to implement used icons like pdf icons by [this app](https://github.com/davedelong/sfsymbols).
A question of approving in App Store you can ask on Apple forum and notify me, I will add theirs answer.

Comment: Sample code how to use sf symbols pdf icons [here](https://github.com/filimo/ReaderTranslator/blob/master/ReaderTranslator/Extentions/Image.swift)